# Python - managing asynchronous methods via threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Within my Python Script I am receiving a constant flow of data but want to push the data asynchronously via calling a asynchronous method. The data which exists in a buffer is always pushed when the method is available.

Inorder to achieve this I have a try/catch that is constantly being called that creates a thread object that executes a method (and I assume returns when the method finishes execution) and if the thread is running the try/catch breaks.

```
import thread
import threading
thr = None
...    

try:
  if thr.is_alive():
    print "thread running"
  else: 
    thr.Thread(target=move_current_data, args=(data_buffer))
    thr.start() 
    data_buffer.clear()
except NameError: 
  print ""   
except AttributeError:
  print "      


def move_current_data(data_buffer):
...    
  return
```

Would there be an easier and cleaner way to write this?

I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Queue. One thread just has the job of monitoring the queue and pushing out any new data. The main thread just adds to the queue when new data is available.

Example:

```
import threading
import queue

def pusher(q):
  while True:
    item = q.get()
    if item is None:
      return         # exit thread
    ...push data...

def main():
  q = Queue.Queue()
  # start up the pusher thread
  t = threading.Thread(target = pusher, args=(q))
  t.start()

  # add items
  q.put(item1)
  ...
  q.put(item2)
  ...
  ...
  # tell pusher to shut down when queue is empty
  # and wait for pusher to complete
  q.put(None)
  t.join()
```

Note that `q.put(...)` does not block the main thread.

Comment: Can I call  t = threading.Thread and t.start() multiple times? There will be times where there can be no data but I don't want the thread to exit

Comment: In my code the pusher thread doesn't exit unless you put a None value onto the queue. So refrain from putting a None value onto the queue until your program is ready to exit. When there is no data the pusher thread just blocks on the `get` call.